# Why is it a problem for Freddie if the guys from Munich did what he wanted?

Tags: dialogue, bohemian-rhapsody

In *Bohemian Rhapsody (2018)*, Freddie is trying to reunite with the Queen Band in front of Jim Beach.

> Freddie: I went to Munich. I hired a bunch of guys. I told them
>   exactly what I wanted them to do...and **the problem was... they did it**.
>   No pushback from Roger. (points to Brian) None of your rewrites.
>   (points to John Deacon)  None of his funny looks. I need you.

Why is it a problem for Freddie if guys from Munich did what he wanted?

Comment: On the other hand, take into account that his two solo albums were quite successful ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddie_Mercury_discography)) but in the concept of the Movie, it is portrait that they weren't and tries to show Freddie wanted to get back to the Queen-type of success, which he could not achieve on his own.

Comment: The rest of the quote appears to give the answer to your question. Particularly the last sentence.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4444/49).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're kind of focusing on the wrong end of the sentiment. It's not so much that they did what Freddie wanted, it's that they never stood up to him or offered any critiques.

What Freddie's trying to concede here is that he did his best work when Brian, Roger, and John were giving their input. The Munich guys were either unable or unwilling to stand up to Freddie's creativity, and so his work wasn't as good.

In short, Freddie found out he is not the perfect musical force he believed he was before he went to Munich, he recognizes that he needs the rest of the band, and he's explaining why he was wrong in abandoning Queen.